# Как менять URL в React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Приложения работает на react-router.(`localhost:3000/`)

Недавно заметил что если написать такой путь `localhost:3000//`приложение загрузит компонент header без ничего также если добавить еще один слеш и еще без остановки то есть при таком url  `localhost:3000///////////` будет тот же результат что  написано наверху.

Я написал небольшое регулярное выражение для того чтобы решить данную задачу `/\/\//g, "/"`.

Попытка первая функция **cleanPath**

```
cleanPath = (path) => {
   return path.replace(/\/\//g, "/");
}
<Route path={this.cleanPath}  component={Test}/>
```

Но такой подход не сработал.

Потом я хотель использовать `history`

```
 <Route path="/" exact  render={({match,location,history}) => {

   if(match == "//"){
      history.push("/")
   }
 return <Test />}}/>
```

Это я написал для теста узнать вообще сработает ли такой код.Тоже не сработал.

И я заметил что это проблема роутера не только у меня.Также это проблема есть у таких сайтов (написанные на реакт) как [**marvel.com**](https://marvel.com//) , [**airbnb.ru**](https://www.airbnb.ru//).

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Не стоит равняться на marvel и airbnb их фрилансеры в свободное от работы время делают

Comment: @Demon __ ANT ReactRouter, если на находит совпадение, отправляет запрос на сервер. Есть вероятность, что header каким-либо образом подтягивается с сервера просто? Какой код js в браузере лежит?

Comment: @Arantler нет.Проста возмите любой код роутера и сделайте так чтобы если user ввел два или больше слешей то перенаправил на основную страницу .Вот к примеру если на этой странице вводить два слеша то он покажет только список ссылок а мне надо чтобы показало основную страницу https://codesandbox.io/s/vVoQVk78

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В офф документации есть пример, и там все работает как надо:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/no-match

```
<Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Redirect from="/old-match" to="/will-match" />
          <Route path="/will-match" component={WillMatch} />
          <Route component={NoMatch} />
```

Comment: действительно рабочий код.А все было так банально надо было проста добавить `<Route component={NoMatch} />`.Спасибо